# PHP filter callback with default value

Tags: php, filter, callback, default-value

Is there a way to define a default value (or to force the callback to be called everytime) when using `filter_var_array` and `FILTER_CALLBACK` ?

Example data:

```
{
    "name": "John"
}
```

Example usage:

```
$params = filter_var_array($datas_from_above, [
    'name' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'age' => [
        'filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK,
        'options' => function ($data) {
            // I was thinking $data would be null here
            // but this function is not called if the 
            // param is not present in the input array.
            die('stop?');
        }
    ]
], true); // Add missing keys as NULL to the return value
```

When using other filters, there's the `default` option. So it shouldn't be  supernatural to have a default value for callback filters.  Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Comment: Don't think it's possible. It's supposed to filter existing data, not create it out of nothing ...

Comment: It seems you're right. Default value is only when validators (boolean, int, etc) don't validate the input. It's not if the input is not here (even if TRUE is the 3 parameter of filter_var_array). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so after some comments and digging, filters in php only process what the input array contains.

So if you want to guarantee that a custom callback is always called, even if the input array doesn't contain the key => value pair, you can do:

```
$partial_input = ["name" => "John"]; // E.g. from a GET request
$defaults = ["name" => null, "age" => null];

$input = array_merge($defaults, $partial_input);

$parsed = filter_var_array($input, [
    "name" => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    "age" => [
        "filter" => FILTER_CALLBACK,
        "options" => function ($data) {
            // do something special if $data === null
        }
    ]
]);
```